# Java - concurrent clear of the list

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, copyonwritearraylist

I am trying to find a good way to achieve the following API:

```
void add(Object o);
void processAndClear();
```

The class would store the objects and upon calling processAndClear would iterate through the currently stored ones, process them somehow, and then clear the store. This class should be thread safe.

the obvious approach is to use locking, but I wanted to be more "concurrent". This is the approach which I would use:

```
class Store{
    private AtomicReference<CopyOnWriteArrayList<Object>> store = new AtomicReference<>(new CopyOnWriteArrayList <>());

    void add(Object o){
        store.get().add(o);
    }

    void processAndClear(){
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Object> objects = store.get();
        store.compareAndSet(objects, new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>());
        for (Object object : objects) {
            //do sth
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow threads that try to add objects to proceed almost immediately without any locking/waiting for the xlearing to complete. Is this the more or less correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your above code is not thread-safe. Imagine the following:

1. Thread A is put on hold at `add()` right after `store.get()`
2. Thread B is in `processAndClear()`, replaces the list, processes all elements of the old one, then returns.
3. Thread A resumes and adds a new item to the now obsolete list that will never be processed.

The probably easiest solution here would be to use a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), which would as well simplify the task a lot:

```
class Store{
  final LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  void add(final Object o){
    queue.put(o); // blocks until there is free space in the optionally bounded queue
  }

  void processAndClear(){
    Object element;
    while ((element = queue.poll()) != null) { // does not block on empty list but returns null instead
      doSomething(element);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** How to do this with `synchronized`:

```
class Store{
  final LinkedList<Object> queue = new LinkedList<>(); // has to be final for synchronized to work

  void add(final Object o){
    synchronized(queue) { // on the queue as this is the shared object in question
      queue.add(o);
    }
  }

  void processAndClear() {
    final LinkedList<Object> elements = new LinkedList<>(); // temporary local list
    synchronized(queue) { // here as well, as every access needs to be properly synchronized
      elements.addAll(queue);
      queue.clear();
    }

    for (Object e : elements) { 
      doSomething(e); // this is thread-safe as only this thread can access these now local elements
    }
  }
}
```

**Why this is not a good idea**

Although this is thread-safe, it is much slower if compared to the concurrent version. Assume that you have a system with 100 threads that frequently call `add`, while one thread calls `processAndClear`. Then the following performance bottle-necks will occur:

- If one thread calls `add` the other 99 are put on hold in the meantime.
- During the first part of `processAndClear` all 100 threads are put on hold.

If you assume that those 100 adding threads have nothing else to do, you can easily show, that the application runs at the same speed as a single-threaded application minus the cost for synchronization. That means: adding will effectively be slower with 100 threads than with 1. This is not the case if you use a concurrent list as in the first example.

There will however be a minor performance gain with the processing thread, as `doSomething` can be run on the old elements while new ones are added. But again the concurrent example could be faster, as you could have multiple threads do the processing *simultaneously*.

Effectively `synchronized` can be used as well, but you will automatically introduce performance bottle-necks, potentially causing the application to run slower as single-threaded, forcing you to do complicated performance tests. In addition extending the functionality always contains a risk of introducing threading issues, as locking needs to be done manually.
A concurrent list in contrast solves all these problems without additional code and the code can easily changed or extended later on.

Comment: Good spot - if I wanted to make sure that only one thread cleans the list at a given time, I could either put  a lock or synchronize the method right? Threads adding to the list are fine.

Comment: If __both__ methods are synchronized/use the same loop then yes, that would work. But on the other hand you would completely destroy threading on that object with those locks.

Comment: Hmm, why do I need to make both methods synchronized? IIf I only lock the process method, that means only one thread can access that at any given time. However, given a thread-safe collection and the fact that I do not care if any other thread adds to a collection while I am processing it, I do not need to put a lock on the add method, do I?

Comment: If you only lock the `processAndClear` method, the bug I described can still happen. Only one thread can process at a time, but any other thread can in the meantime add additional elements at any inconvenient moment.

Comment: Adding seems OK right? The Queue would still be thread safe i.e. LinkedBlockingQueue for instance, so even if inserts occur from other threads while we process that is fine in terms of thread safety.

Comment: If you use a LinkedBlockingQueue you can add at any time using the standard features of that list. It will ensure that thread-safety is maintained at all times. If you use non-concurrent queues, adding will cause issues as those lists are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

> The class would store the objects and upon calling processAndClear would iterate through the currently stored ones, process them somehow, and then clear the store.

This seems like you should use a `BlockingQueue` for this task.  Your `add(...)` method would add to the queue and your consumer would call `take()` which blocks waiting for the next item.  The `BlockingQueue` (`ArrayBlockingQueue` is a typical implementation) takes care of all of the synchronization and signaling for you.

This means that you don't have to have a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` nor an `AtomicReference`.  What you would lose is a collection and you can iterate through for other reasons than your post articulates currently.